# Need help! kernel compilation error!

Tags: kernel, dpkg, compiling

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekHpIfiUt8M i followed this guide, unfortunately TWICE got this error :

> make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dante/kernel/linux-4.2'
>   scripts/kconfig/conf  --silentoldconfig Kconfig make[2]: Leaving
>   directory`/home/dante/kernel/linux-4.2' make[2]: Entering directory
>   `/home/dante/kernel/linux-4.2' sh ./arch/x86/boot/install.sh
>   4.2.0-dante-core arch/x86/boot/bzImage \      System.map "/home/dante/kernel/linux/debian/linux-image-4.2.0-dante-core//boot"
>   run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal
>   4.2.0-dante-core /home/dante/kernel/linux/debian/linux-image-4.2.0-dante-core//boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-dante-core
>   /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal: 84:
>   /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal: cannot create
>   /etc/apt/apt.conf.d//01autoremove-kernels.dpkg-new: Permission denied
>   run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal exited with return
>   code 2 make[3]: *** [install] Error 1 make[2]: *** [install] Error 2
>   make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/dante/kernel/linux-4.2' make[1]: ***
>   [debian/stamp/install/linux-image-4.2.0-dante-core] Error 2 make[1]:
>   Leaving directory `/home/dante/kernel/linux-4.2' make: ***
>   [kernel_image] Error 2

Kernel compilation takes A LOT of time on my pc, this is such a disappointment when after 3 hours of compilation  i get this freakin error and .deb package doesn't even appear. I am new to linux, please tell me what am i doing wrong? ubuntu version 14.04, my pc is asus k53sc. I beg you for help guys i really want to understand what am i doing wrong.

Comment: i forgot to say that kernel version that i wish to compile is stable 4.2.0

Comment: And which command produces the error?

Comment: the last one, i mentioned the youtube guide, i used the command he uses: `fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-my-version-name kernel_image kernel_headers`

Answer (score 0):

i found out what was the problem. I installed kernel-package_13.003_all.deb and it worked. My kernel config sucks tho, don't see real increase in speed